# Update formulas from cell string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a sheet with a multitude of formulae for generating reports. Examples of the formulae are:

```
=countifs(Wk27_28_data!Z:Z,"no",Wk27_28_data!J:J,"<>Update",Wk27_28_data!J:J,"<>With Customer",Wk27_28_data!J:J,"<>In Progress",Wk27_28_data!C:C,"<>Change",Wk27_28_data!J:J,"<>With Supplier")

=Wk27_28_data!B5

=countifs(Wk27_28_data!D:D,A6,Wk27_28_data!C:C,"Automated Alert")

=COUNTIF(Wk27_28_data!F:F,A29)
```

Ideally what I want to be able to do is remove the 27_28 from the formulae and put it in to another cell which is then referenced by all the formulae, and thus I would be able to update them all just by changing this one cell. Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!Z:Z"), "no",
          INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!J:J"), "<>Update",
          INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!J:J"), "<>With Customer",
          INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!J:J"), "<>In Progress",
          INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!C:C"), "<>Change",
          INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!J:J"), "<>With Supplier")
```

---

```
=INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!B5")
```

---

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!D:D"), A6,
          INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!C:C"), "Automated Alert")
```

---

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"data!F:F"), A29)
```

where A1 cell = `27_28`

Comment: I thought it may be something along these lines, I just couldn't get it to work properly, thanks!

For future reference, if I wanted to create a sheet quickly (i.e. click and drag to fill a series with the INDIRECT), is it possible to have the other cell references outside of the quote marks so that they auto increment?

E.g. =INDIRECT("Wk"&A1&"_data!"&B5) so that the B5 increments to B6,B7 etc....as I have been unable to get this to work?

Comment: @Ikthezeus yes, try dragging down: `=INDIRECT("Wk"&A$1&"_data!"&B5)` (notice the $ for freezing the row)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Wk27_28` text is entered in cell A1. Replace

```
=Wk27_28_data!B5
```

with

```
=INDIRECT("Wk"&$A$1&"_data!B5",TRUE)
```

and do the same for others.

Please share if it works/understandable/not.